# Fetch Data using Vue http based on Router params

Tags: javascript, vue.js, get, vuejs2, xmlhttprequest

I have searched around for an answer to this and also followed the example on the [vue router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html) but am still having issues. I am trying to do an http call on initial load of a component and then also watch the router params and update the 'get' call from vue-resource.

My vue component js looks like this...

```
export default {
  name: 'city',
  components: {
    Entry
  },
  data () {
    return {
      city: null
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
  },
  watch: {
    '$route': 'fetchData'
  },
  methods: {
    fetchData() {
      const cityName = this.$route.params.name;
      this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/cities?short=' + cityName).then(function(response){
        this.city = response.data;
      }, function(error){
        alert(error.statusText);
      });
      console.log(cityName)
    }
  }
}
```

I have logged out the 'cityName' in my fetchData method and it always returns the right name, but when I append that 'cityName' to the http get call it is not returning the proper data. On initial load, this.city remains null and then each time I update the route, the data returns with the previous city selected instead of the new updated city in the route. I have tried Vue's `created` property in place of `mounted` and the same thing happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried hitting the endpoint manually (i.e. curl) to make sure it's returning the correct data?

Comment: Could you try adding `:key="$route.fullPath"` to your `<router-view>` component.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your `fetchData` method to the following:

```
fetchData() {
  const cityName = this.$route.params.name;
  this.$http.get('http://localhost:3000/cities?short=' + cityName).then((response) => {
    this.city = response.data;
  }, (error) => {
    alert(error.statusText);
  });
  console.log(cityName)
}
```

The `=>` function notation keeps `this` in context of the component.

Comment: Apparently, changing to 'created' and moving that created method to the end of my component works for some reason. But now the issue is that when I bind that data in the component's template (or pass to a child component), I get an error cannot read property of undefined. Do I need to make the component async somehow? Thanks for your help.